# Straight lines and triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

AB and CD are two fixed straight lines and a variable straight line cuts them at X and Y respectively .The angular bisectors of angle AXY and angle CXY meet at P.Find the locus of P.

My answer is P lies on AB ,Is this correct ?

Comment: I believe it should be angle CYX instead.

Comment: its CXY ,does the answer change then ?

Comment: If it is CXY, the point of intersection P is actually X all the time. Your answer is correct but the question is then meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is the figure for the actual question.
[image]

Note: this is just part of the answer.